# Uploading an image from phone storage

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to make a user upload an image file from his/her phone gallery into my app. I have managed to invoke the gallery but as the user selects an image. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/7963 (has extras) }} to activity {com.progrmor.tombstone.android/com.progrmor.tombstone.android.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/7963 from pid=16802, uid=10409 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4060)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/7963 from pid=16802, uid=10409 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Below are the codes invoking the gallery:

```
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    if(response == RESULT_OK) {
        if(request == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImage);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    // just some safety built in
    if( uri == null ) {
        // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
        return null;
    }
    // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
    // this will only work for images selected from gallery
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    // this is our fallback here
    return uri.getPath();
}

@Override
public void imageUpload() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });

}
```

Then I simply call that method in one of my screen classes:

```
boxImage1.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            imageUpload();
        }
    });
}
```

So what I'm asking is: How can I make a click on a picture to upload that actual picture into say a texture or something? I just want their chosen image to be drawn on the screen when they pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add proper permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. Do you have any suggestion on how to take the image into the screen? Since I´ve never worked with external storage before.

Comment: You already have this `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`  so just hook it to ImageView like `imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage)`

Comment: Ah I see. Just one more thing I would like to ask you. I need to pass this path into another class, I use an interface for that. But how would I pass this? Can I pass the imageView if I set it as you shown me?

Comment: What is the other class ? As long as it's not another Activity then it's ok to pass the ImageView.

Comment: It´s a screen class simply. Thanks for you help!